# Solving $x|x-1|<3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Seems pretty straight-forward but I'm a bit confused with the modulus and inequality.

So I know that if

> $|x-1|>3$

because the entire equation on the left is within the modulus we can write

> $x-1>3$ or $x-1<-3$

I also know that if $y<0$

> $y|x-1|>3$

Can be written as

> $|x-1|<3/y$

But what do we do with

> $x|x-1|<3$

Can we break it down further without trying to input values?

Comment: What is the range of your solutions? Do you include real numbers, integers or something else?

Comment: Lets assume all integers

Comment: There's actually a smarter way to do this problem – which is to separate it into $x < 0$, $0 < x < 1$, and $1, 2, 3 \cdots$.

Comment: @TobyMak I don't think I understand the smarter way that you are talking about. Do you mean putting values?

Comment: If $x < 0$, $x$ is negative but $|x-1|$ is positive, so $x|x-1|$ is negative and $<0$. If $0<x<1$, $x < 1$ and $|x-1| ≤ 1$, so $x|x-1|$ is at most $1$. Now you can check the cases $1, 2, 3$ separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it like this. For $x>1$ the equation is equivalent to $x(x-1)<3$ this gives $x^2-x-3<0$ Roots of this equation are $$\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}, \frac{1-\sqrt{13}}{2}$$
So this gives the range $x\in(1, \frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2})$

For $x<1$ the equation is $-x(x-1)<3$ or $x^2-x+3>0$ this always satisfied for any values of $x$. Hence $x\in(-\infty, \frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2})$, taking $x$ to be integers would make this $x\le2$.

Comment: The inequality trivially satisfied for non-positive $x$.

Comment: @A.Γ. How about when $0 < x < 1$? (I just realised when that happens, $x|x-1| < 1 \cdot 1 < 3$.)

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar $x=3$ doesn't work as well.

Comment: I have corrected.

Comment: Nitpicking: you're neglecting the case $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

This method doesn't generalize, but it may be instructive. The inequality surely holds for $x\le0$, so we can concentrate on $x>0$. Dividing both sides by $x$, we obtain
$$
|x-1|<\frac{3}{x}
$$
that's equivalent to
$$
-\frac{3}{x}<x-1<\frac{3}{x}
$$
that in turn becomes
\begin{cases}
x^2-x+3 > 0 \\[4px]
x^2-x-3 < 0
\end{cases}
The top one is true for every $x$; the bottom one is satisfied for
$$
0<x<\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}
$$
(recall we're restricting to $x>0$).

Putting back the interval $x\le0$ we discussed before, we can conclude the solution set is
$$
x<\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cases where $x > 1$ and where $x < 1$.

If $x > 1$, we have:
$$x(x-1) < 3$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2-x-3 < 0$$

With $x=2$, we have $2^2-2-3 = -1 < 0$, and with $x = 3$ we have $3^2 - 3 - 3 = 3 > 0$, so $x ≤ 2$.

If $x < 1$, we have:
$$x(x+1) < 3$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2+x-3 < 0$$

Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the graph of $y=x(x-1)$:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

If the absolute values are applied to get $y=x|x-1|$, the graph becomes:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

The point $A$ has coordinates $x(x-1)=3 \Rightarrow x=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}$ and $y=3$.

Hence, the solution of the inequality $x|x-1|<3$ is:
$$x\in \left(-\infty,\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right).$$